# Code signing using a Sectigo certificate on github

Tags: macos, code-signing, github-actions, electron-builder

I have an electron app that is built in a github action. The action builds an installation for Macs and Windows, using `windows-latest` and `macos-latest` on github. The action is working properly.

Recently I have obtained a code signing certificate from Sectigo (a regular non-EV certificate). When I set the `CSC_LINK` and `CSC_KEY_PASSWORD` environment variables on both Windows and Mac physical machines, `electron-builder` signs the package properly.

On github, the Windows job signs the package properly, but the Mac job fails with the following error:

```
Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "*******"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
/Users/runner/work/t2wml/t2wml/electron/out/mac/t2wml.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron 
Framework.framework/Versions/A/Helpers/chrome_crashpad_handler: errSecInternalComponent
```

(the signer name is the actual name on the certificate, not *****)

The certificate itself is not self-signed, as is evident by looking at the digital signature of the Windows executable created by the same github action (a different job that uses exactly the same repo secrets).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it really make sense to use a Sectigo certificate on a macOS app? Usually, the reason to sign a Mac app is to allow the Gatekeeper system to recognize the app as coming from a known developer, and Gatekeeper only recognizes Apple-issued certificates (specifically, [Developer ID certificates](https://developer.apple.com/developer-id/)).

Comment: That is a good question, but still, since I *can* sign with the Sectigo certificate on my physical mac, why can't I do it in github?

Comment: That I do not know. It sounds a bit like an intermediate certificate is missing somewhere, but I'm not familiar with github's signing system, so that's just a wild guess.